# What is small-signal resistance of MOSFET?

Tags: resistance

[image: CS Stage]

In a NMOS transistor, we have a current formula for saturation region.

$$I = \frac{1}{2}(\mu_n)(C_{ox})\Big(\frac{W}{L}\Big)(V_{GS} - V_{TH})^2$$

We bias the MOS with a \$V_b\$ in order for the NMOS to be operational in Saturation and apply small-signal \$V_{in}\$.
If channel-length modulation presents, \$r_o = \dfrac{1}{\lambda I_d}\$, and this resistance persists even if no small-signal. 
In Razavi book Fundamentals of Microelectronics, I see the term small-signal resistance on page 400 2nd edition, "MOS Cascode". Can any body help?

Answer (score 1):

The resistance r<sub>0</sub> is a parameter of the mosfet which does not depend on small signal or any other signal. Whereas, small signal resistance is the resistance you see at the output on applying a small signal input, that is

[image]

and the output resistance is

[image]